Cups Web Interface "Add Printer" interface softlocked
I tried to follow this guide: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=49714
It mentioned restarting CUPS, so I did "systemctl restart cups". And then THIS happened!

The damn thing is just completely BROKEN now!
Tried removing the files that guide dropped in the system and restarting CUPS. Still broken.
How do I fix this?

The "nuclear option" works!
sudo apt purge cups
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install cups

The "Add Printer" wizard has its options again!
